# Show Color on WrkStat.aspx Page

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, colors

On the WrkStat.aspx page I would like to add emphasis to the status of each approval stage.  e.g. I want to show "Approved" in green and "Rejected" text in red.

I tried editing the page in SharePoint Designer but it gives an error about application.master.

Does anyone know how to add color to this wrkstat.aspx page or any custom workflow status page?

Comment: Not an answer but you may find some inspiration in this blog post
http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/09/01/apply-color-coding-to-your-sharepoint-lists/

Comment: Thanks Ryan.  I have the inspiration unfortunately but not the answer of how to do this.

It's easy to apply the colour coding to a list but the WrkStat.aspx page (or custom page) is not easily editable in SPD as in the example you posted.

There's also no way to add a HTML field to the WrkStat.aspx page it seems so then adding a CEWP for the colouring is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

I see that in this page columns (f.ex. title with link to item) are still diplayed with their render (or display?) pattern. If you can choose columns visible in this view, you can add here your own column with custom display pattern. In this pattern you can set color depends on field value, etc.

If managing columns in WrkStat insn't possible, You can change display pattern of "result" field type and write your own column to still have "old style" field with the same functionality. But first solution is much better.